# iOS7.1 keyboard blur

Tags: ios

[image]I was developing an app and I ran into this issue. How would I achieve a keyboard background blur like the one in youtubes iphone/iPad app? I can't figure it out. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: The YouTube App on my iPhone is black. What do you mean exactly? Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: I'm not on my computer now so I cannot check it myself, but isn't that the "alert keyboard type" or something like this?  On the textField properties you can select which kind of keyboard will it call. On my iPad the keyboard is opaque black, not translucent. Maybe you can set also the alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Keyboard appearance property to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`.

### Example

```
[textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

### From the documentation

```
//
// UIKeyboardAppearance
//
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIKeyboardAppearance) {
    UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault,          // Default apperance for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardAppearanceDark NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0),
    UIKeyboardAppearanceLight NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0),
    UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark,  // Deprecated
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This effect happens as part of the iOS 7.1 SDK. Upgrade your devices to iOS 7.1 and your Xcode to 5.1 and above, and you will see it.

To get the darker keyboard, you need to set the `keyboardAppearance` property of the text field or text view to `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`.